# What is the probability distribution of this set?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I repeat the following process:

I flip a fair coin, and observe the first result (say it's heads), and then I flip it n times until it's no longer heads (or tails, if it was the first result). I repeat this process indefinitely and record n each time. For example, the sequence HHHT means n = 3, and the sequence HHHTHTHHHH would give the set of values for n {3,1,1,1,4}

What is the distribution of n? I feel it should not be uniformly distributed. Am I right?

Comment: This is called a geometric distribution.

Comment: If this process is done $1024 = 2^{10}$ times, I would expect $512$ (1's), $256$ (2's), $128$ (3's), $\cdots~$.